# Removing cookies with the same name but different paths

Tags: javascript, cookies, path, client-side

I need to delete clientside cookies with the same name but with different paths. What is the best way to do this in javascript.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just specify the same path of the cookie you want to remove, giving it a past expiration.

```
document.cookie = 'name=value1; path=/';
document.cookie = 'name=value2; path=/path/';

alert(document.cookie); // name=value1; name=value2


document.cookie = 'name=; path=/path/; expires=' + new Date(0).toUTCString();

alert(document.cookie); // name=value1
```

Changing it to expire the cookie with a path of `/` will still only expire one of the cookies -- the path given has to match the path set:

```
document.cookie = 'name=; path=/; expires=' + new Date(0).toUTCString();

alert(document.cookie); // name=value2
```

To remove both, you'll have to expire each with their path:

```
document.cookie = 'name=; path=/; expires=' + new Date(0).toUTCString();
document.cookie = 'name=; path=/path/; expires=' + new Date(0).toUTCString();

alert(document.cookie); // {blank}
```

Now, these examples assume you're browsing `/path/` or a sub-directory of it.

---

[edit]

To remove in bulk, try something like this:

```
function expireAllCookies(name, paths) {
    var expires = new Date(0).toUTCString();

    // expire null-path cookies as well
    document.cookie = name + '=; expires=' + expires;

    for (var i = 0, l = paths.length; i < l; i++) {
        document.cookie = name + '=; path=' + paths[i] + '; expires=' + expires;
    }
}

expireAllCookies('name', ['/', '/path/']);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/M2dZ3/

You can also fake path lookups by splitting and iterating `window.location.pathname`:

```
function expireActiveCookies(name) {
    var pathname = location.pathname.replace(/\/$/, ''),
        segments = pathname.split('/'),
        paths = [];

    for (var i = 0, l = segments.length, path; i < l; i++) {
        path = segments.slice(0, i + 1).join('/');

        paths.push(path);       // as file
        paths.push(path + '/'); // as directory
    }

    expireAllCookies(name, paths);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/M2dZ3/2/

Comment: So if path can potentially contain 6 different values, I should use 6x  document.cookie with the right path?

Comment: @JKown Essentially. Though, I would suggest looping over the paths so you only have 1 `document.cookie` statement. See my edit for one option.

Comment: One follow up question. Is it possible to "feed" the path array with the paths in the cookies? As in; can I get the path from a cookie?

Comment: @JKown Not really as `document.cookie` only returns names and values. However, as cookies are only available if its path relates to the current path, you can kind of fake it by splitting and iterating `window.location.pathname`. See my latest edit.

Comment: In some browsers the path has to be specified without the trailing slash.