# Avoid page refresh and add values to javascript session?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to add two products to comparison queue like on this site (http://www.phonearena.com/phones/manufacturers/Samsung) Here if you hover on a mobile phone and click on 'compare+' it add to a java-script or browser session and if you open another page and click on next any mobile 'compare+' button, it adds up to the comparison queue, which you can later use to compare two mobiles.
I want to know what should I do, to achieve this functionality. My web app is being developed in MVC3 and I want to compare two of my products this way.

Please I just need some help how to figure this out.
Thanks

Comment: Are cookies acceptable?  If so, store your choice state in a session cookie for the site.

Comment: Or localStorage. Either would work.

Comment: @KirkB.: Yes cookies are acceptable. I just want to know whats the best way for this functionality. What do you suggest?

Comment: @MikeRobinson: HTML5 localStorage? or browser session?

Comment: HTML5... honestly it doesn't really matter than much what you use. @KirkB is suggesting the easiest, most reliable solution with cookies. All you really need to do is remember a list of product IDs.

Comment: @MikeRobinson: Yes, I just checked with firbug, they are also using cookies with session. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give

http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

a try.  Something like:

```
if ($.cookie("choices"))
{
    // have previous choice, so handle comparison display and reset state

    // ...

    $.removeCookie("choices");
}
else
{
    $.cookie("choices", "key of first product");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you would use cookies:

```
document.cookie = "mobile1=" + mobile1;
```

and then you can retrieve it like so:

```
mobile1 = document.cookie
```

Comment: I will surely try that.

Comment: This approach may work for you, but when you retrieve the cookie value, you're actually getting all cookies for your site with that call.  Do you only plan to use one cookie for your site?  If so, then fine.  $.cookie plugin sorts those issues out for you.

Comment: @KirkB. can I retrieve cookies from a specific Path? I can erase the existing cookies at the time of onclick compare button call.

Comment: I suppose you can do both.  Here is a similar issue with some worked out use of setting a cookie with a path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487210/removing-cookies-with-the-same-name-but-different-paths

Comment: Here's an issue where they worked out being explicit with path using the jQuery cookie plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326620/jquery-cookie-path

Comment: Don't forget to pick an answer :)